# How to add list of lists in a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list which is produced by a list comprehension and it sorts the data in `stripped` according to groups by finding which strings have a length of 3 and I want to merge them so that are in a single list separately from single length strings.

```
stripped = ['a,b', 'c,d', 'e', '', 'f,g', 'h', '', '']
lst = [[i.split(',')] if len(i) is 3 else i for i in stripped]
print(lst)
#[[['a', 'b']], [['c', 'd']], 'e', '', [['f', 'g']], 'h', '', '']
```

I want to produce `[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'],['f', 'g']], 'e', '','h', '', '']` instead

How can I achieve this with a **Single** list-comprehension if *possible*?

## Edit:

accepted [@HennyH's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19615921/2425215) answer because of its high efficiency and simplicity

Comment: You'll need two comprehensions.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac just what I was afraid of... BTW I'll move on with that If I *must*

Comment: @KDawG You can also simply sort the list - see my answer.

Comment: @KDawG Afraid of 2 LCs, why?

Comment: @hcwhsa It might use a whole lot of resources, my actual list is so damn large that running it over twice is expensive!

Comment: @KDawG I've found a way of doing it on one.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac please post that as an answer then........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l = [[]]
for e in stripped:
    (l[0] if len(e) == 3 else l).append(e)
>>> 
[['a,b', 'c,d', 'f,g'], 'e', '', 'h', '', '']
```

Or to match the OP's output for the 3 long strings:

```
for e in stripped:
    l[0].append(e.split(',')) if len(e) == 3 else l.append(e)
>>> 
[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'g']], 'e', '', 'h', '', '']
```

This way there is no additional concatenation of two lists `A`,`B` as Inbar's solution provided. You can also turn `stripped` into a generator expression so you don't need to hold the two lists in memory.

Comment: Good But actually it should be: `(l[0] if len(e) == 3 else l).append(e.split(','))`

Comment: @HennyH but wait that will outputs `[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'g']], ['e'], [''], ['h'], [''], ['']]` that is not exactly same as OP wants

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan fixed it up

Comment: @HennyH Really Nice answer, Very Good :)

Answer (score 2):

Use two list comprehensions:

```
>>> stripped = ['a,b', 'c,d', 'e', '', 'f,g', 'h', '', '']
>>> first = [x.split(',') for x in (item for item in stripped if len(item) == 3)]
>>> second = [item for item in stripped if len(item) != 3]
>>> [first] + second
[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'g']], 'e', '', 'h', '', '']
```

Answer (score 2):

Why require list comprehension? Better to do it in 1 pass.

```
stripped = ['a,b', 'c,d', 'e', '', 'f,g', 'h', '', '']
groups = []
final = [groups]
for item in stripped:
    if len(item) == 3:
        groups.append(item.split(','))
    else:
        final.append(item)
```

Result:

```
>>> print(final) 
[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'g']], 'e', '', 'h', '', '']
```

Comment: You could even add with `B = [A]` before the loop, and fully meet the single-pass requirement. (The final `[A]+B` is technically a *pass* over `B`, although a very efficient one.)

Comment: @user4815162342 That is true.